# How to create Route for TabbedForm react-admin

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I use Drawer to make create/show/edit pages.I have an edit page that is in a TabbedForm and I can't acces all FormTabs.When I try to edit in first FormTab it works, but the other FormTab doesn't work, it dissapear(I guess this happens because I do not include that second FormTab in the Drawer, but for Create it works fine :-D).
To sum up, I don't know how to create that additional Route for the second FormTab.

```
class AdminList extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { push, classes, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <List
                {...props}
                sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }}
                actions={<AdminListActions />}
            >
                <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <NameField source="name" />
                    <TextField source="email" />
                    <TextField source="type" />
                    <FunctionField label="Permissions" render={record => `${(record.permissions === null) ? 'none' : objectList(record.permissions)}`} />
                    <ShowButton />
                    <EditButton />
                    <DeleteButton undoable={false} />
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
            <Route path="/admin/create">
                    {({ match }) => (
                    <Drawer
                        open={match ? true : false} 
                        anchor="right"
                        onClose={this.handleClose}
                    >
                        <AdminCreate
                            className={classes.drawerContent}
                            onCancel={this.handleClose}
                            {...props}
                        />
                    </Drawer>
                )}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/admin/:id/show">
                {({ match }) => {

                    const isMatch =
                        match &&
                        match.params &&
                        match.params.id !== 'create';

                        return (
                        <Drawer
                            open={!!isMatch}
                            anchor="right"
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                        >
                            {isMatch ? (
                                <AdminShow
                                    className={classes.drawerContent}
                                    id={isMatch ? match.params.id : null}
                                    onCancel={this.handleClose}
                                    {...props}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <div className={classes.drawerContent} />
                            )}
                        </Drawer>
                    );
                }}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/admin/edit/:id">
                {({ match }) => {

                    let isMatch =
                        match &&
                        match.params &&
                        (match.params.id !== 'create')
                        && match.isExact;

                    return (
                        <Drawer
                            open={(isMatch===true)}
                            anchor="right"
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                        >
                            {isMatch ? (
                                <AdminEdit
                                    className={classes.drawerContent}
                                    id={isMatch ? match.params.id : null}
                                    onCancel={this.handleClose}
                                    {...props}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <div className={classes.drawerContent} />
                            )}
                        </Drawer>
                    );
                }}
            </Route>

        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

I want to be able to edit all FormTabs from a TabbedForm(to acces them actually). Thanx!
Also,this is my AdminEdit component:

```
const AdminEdit = ({ onCancel, ...props }) => (
<Edit undoable={false} title=" " {...props}>
    <TabbedForm toolbar={<AdminEditToolbar onCancel={onCancel} />}>
        <FormTab label="main">
            <DisabledInput source="id" />
            <DisabledInput source="businessId" />
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="email" validate={required()} />
            <TextInput source="password" validate={required()} />
            <TextInput source="type" />
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="permissions">
            <CustomCheckbox {...props} />
        </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
</Edit>
```

Comment: I solved my problem, I used something else.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a codesandbox so we can play with the idea. However, I think that's because your edit route is too restrictive. Indeed, we mount tabs inside a sub route too: `/admin/edit/:id/:tab`. By default each tab is simply assigned a number as its path but you can override it using its `path` prop